# Game corrupted; how can I fix it?

Tags: technical-issues, naruto-ultimate-ninja-3

The game name is  **Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 Full Burst - PC**.

Today I was playing this game and I completed a mission, after that game was saving, but while it was doing this, my computer suddenly turned off.
Now I am opening the game then it shows some logos than trailer and then shows start-up screen. On this screen shows click to start when I click to start the game, it stop right there but I can hear the sound of game that it is playing but it isn't showing.
**Updated**

This is the image of folder of the game. Can you have idea about where are its user files.
[image]

Why did this happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the game files got corrupted because it was interrupted while saving.

Re installing the game should fix this.

Something else you could try if you dont want to uninstall is go into the settings and mess around with things to try and fix the corrupted data by saving over it.

If you want to save the progress (if it isn't whats borked). You can simply move the save folders to a different location on your filesystem then proceed with the reinstall, and then put the files back.

Comment: Well I know this can solve the problem but it would remove my missions and I would have to play it from start.

Comment: @Tester Since when does reinstalling remove missions or kill save games?

Comment: @Frank sometimes uninstalling means losing your save data as well. Depends on the game. Since The saves themselves are whats corrupted most likely. You'd need to kill them anyway. There's a warning about "do not turn off while saving" for a reason.

Comment: So is there any way to save it's user files and re-install the game?

Comment: @Tester I updated the answer with additional possible solutions.

Comment: I think this problem is related to user save files because I have two account on one computer and this game is working on another account  on same PC also I don't know where are it's user files.

Comment: @Rapitor I have updated the question with picture of folder of the game. Do you have idea about where can it's users files be?

Comment: Data looks suspicious... but sometimes game saves are in a completely different directory. a quick google search gave me "C:\Users\"Your Name"l\AppData\Local\EMU\Steam\234670\remote" so look there.

Comment: I also have a problem with another game. check it (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170263/windows-continully-minimizes-splinter-cell-conviction)